# add element JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to add new element to JSON ...

```js
var estudiantes = [
  {"Nombre":"Fernando","Codigo":"F50","Nota":100}
  ];
```

and this is the function to add the element, but doesnt works ...

```js
function addEstudiantes(){
    var nombre = prompt("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante: ");
 var codigo = prompt("Ingrese el codigo del estudiante: ");
 var nota = prompt("Ingrese la nota del estudiante: ");
 /*agregar registro al JSON*/
 var objeto = JSON.parse(estudiantes);
 objeto.push('{"Nombre":"'+nombre+'","Codigo":"'+codigo+'","Nota":'+nota+'}');
 estudiantes = JSON.stringify(objeto);
}
```

Comment: Just try: `objeto.push({"Nombre": nombre,"Codigo":codigo,"Nota":nota});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you aren't working with json, you are working with a javascript array of objects but trying to push json string instead of object into it

Try

```
function addEstudiantes(){
    var nombre = prompt("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante: ");
    var codigo = prompt("Ingrese el codigo del estudiante: ");
    var nota = prompt("Ingrese la nota del estudiante: ");
    // create new object
    var objeto = {"Nombre":nombre,"Codigo":codigo,"Nota":nota};
    //push object into array
    estudiantes.push( objeto);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are working in js, you dont need work this like a string , you need work this with objects.

```js
var linea= [];
var persona = new Object();
var objeto = new Object();
function addEstudiantes(){
    var nombre = prompt("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante: ");
    var codigo = prompt("Ingrese el codigo del estudiante: ");
    var nota = prompt("Ingrese la nota del estudiante: ");
    // create new object    
  persona.nombre=nombre;
  persona.codigo=codigo;
  persona.nota=nota;
  linea.push(persona);
  
  }
function generarjson(){
  objeto.estudiantes=linea;
  alert(JSON.stringify(objeto));
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="addEstudiantes();">Agregar estudiante</button>
<button onclick="generarjson();">Generar JSON</button>
```